# find element based on tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabindex

Using jquery or javascript, how can I find the input element in the DOM that has a particular tabindex set to it, eg.

```
<input id="txtInput" type="text" maxlength="5" tabindex="7">
```

I would want this element returned if I was searching for the element with tabindex = 7.

Comment: This is not how tabindex is used. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get it with the following jQuery

```
$('input[tabindex=7]')
```

Comment: This is much better as it will get only the `input` element having `TabIndex=7`

Answer (score 8):

With the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("[tabindex=7]") // all elements with tabindex=7
```

Answer (score 8):

You can find the element by an attribute selector:

```
$('[tabindex=7]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[tabindex='7']");
```

And if you want all elements, not just inputs, with a tabindex attribute of seven:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex='7']");
```

However, [MDN recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) avoiding tabindex values greater than zero as it may be confusing, especially for those using screen readers.