# VBS: Can I target a field by its tabIndex, and its div position?

Tags: html, input, vbscript, tabindex

Novice here, using VBS to help with data entry to a web input form. Would appreciate any advice. I regularly use lines like this to set the value of a field based on its name:

```
IE.Document.All.Item("field1").Value = "test"
```

However I have a set of very awkward fields whose **names** change with each record. Their physical positions stay the same (visually); their tabIndexes stay the same (1,2,3,4), so I wondered if it's possible to do something like this:

```
IE.Document.All.getElementByTabIndex(1).Value = "test"
```

...But I'm not sure it is? Furthermore, even if that did work, tabIndex1 is used for another field on the same webpage. The fields that I am interested in, however, are all located on a div. The ID of the div is "form_div". So I'm trying to target a field located on div "form_div" whose tabIndex is 1... do you think it is possible?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872386/find-element-based-on-tabindex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a `DIV` element with `tabIndex` set to 1 and you don't know it `Name` or `ID`, right? Then do something like this:

```
Set oDivs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
Set myDiv = Nothing
For Each od In oDivs
    If od.tabIndex = "1" Then
        Set myDiv = od
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not myDiv Is Nothing Then
    'do what needs here...
    MsgBox myDiv.Name
End If
```

**P.S.** Well, I see 2 drawbacks in your design.

1. The `tabIndex` should be unique.
2. Searching for element by name is not so perfect in IE. If your
   element has only `Name` and not `ID` then `getElementsByName` will
   fail. Better use `ID`, it's even simplify coding:

   ```
   Set myDiv = IE.Document.All.form_div
   ```

To find it by Name w'd be:

```
Set oDivs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
Set myDiv = Nothing
For Each od In oDivs
    If od.Name = "form_div" Then
        Set myDiv = od
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

And once you have the element...

```
If Not myDiv Is Nothing Then
    Set nodes = myDiv.childNodes
    For i = 0 To nodes.Length-1 Step 2
        If nodes(i).tabIndex = "1" Then
            'do what need here...
            nodes(i).Value = nodes(i).tabIndex
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Panayot, thanks, this is interesting but this is not exactly my problem... I am trying to set the value of a field on a div. I know the name of the div ("form_div"), and I know the tabIndex of the field (1). I can't just use the tabIndex because there's another field on the same webpage with a tabIndex of 1 - not in the same div. So I need to plant my value in the input field with tabIndex 1, on div "form_div". Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Thanks, Panayot. This feels like we're getting close, but when I run this, I get the message "object doesn't support this property or method: 'od.Name' ". Then... where you comment "do what need here", I don't understand how to set the value of the field to my text. Sorry for being dumb, please can you elaborate? Thanks again for your help, so much.

Comment: @David - Well, if `od.Name` return such error then looks like your element has not `Name` attribute. Are you sure you have something like `<div name="form_div">`? If not but you have `ID` then it's even better, i.e. if it `<div id="form_div">` you can get it as I post above: `Set myDiv = IE.Document.All.form_div`.

Comment: I'm sorry - you're absolutely right, my div has an ID, not a name. The ID is "form_div". So this is good news! Thank you. OK... I have a test project where I have created a simplified version of the webpage, and your code is working perfectly, thank you _very_ much. I can't get it working with the real webpage yet, I'm thinking it might have something to do with the field being part of a form. I'll continue to experiment.